# how to make matplotlib stack subplots with different amounts of columns?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have two rows of subpolots but an overall odd amount of plots (2 rows, one with 5 columns and the other with four columns. I would like to have subplots show the first row with 5 columns and the bottom rown with four columns, but I would like the four columns in the bottom row to be stacked like bricks...

```
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |  --> row 1
  | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 |    --> row 2
```

But I cannot quite figure out how to do this by the docs. Is there anyway to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Let's try [`subplot2grid`](https://matplotlib.org/3.0.2/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplot2grid.html#matplotlib.pyplot.subplot2grid):

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(2*row1,3))

for i in range(row1):
    ax = plt.subplot2grid((2,2*row1), (0,2*i), colspan=2)
    # plot something
    ax.plot([0,1])

for i in range(row1-1):
    ax = plt.subplot2grid((2,2*row1), (1,2*i+1), colspan=2)
    
    #plot something
    ax.plot([0,1])

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]